# YouTube video loaded into Flash MovieClip, can I get width and height?

Tags: actionscript-3, youtube, size, width

I'm trying to load a YouTube video on a flash MovieClip using url
http://www.youtube.com/v/4nRNoXT_gUc that returns the video with player directly.

the video is loaded and i can manage it with his player, the problem is when i try to position it no the stage, because I don't know his width until it starts.

I've tested it with Event.ENTER_FRAME but when the video starts it return width = 10000
how can i do to know his width or height?

Comment: I think 425x344 is the default video size in youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the movie's nominal width and height through the loader's **contentLoaderInfo** object. Just try the following :

```
trace(loader.contentLoaderInfo.width);
```

The nominal width and height of your movie is 640x480. You will notice, however, that the movie is being scaled down (probably by YouTube, would need to be confirmed).

Also, be aware that what is returned by YouTube is an **AVM1Movie** object. An **AVM1Movie** object is an SWF that was compiled under ActionScript 2 (in YouTube's case, most likely Flash version 8). The interaction that is possible with an **AVM1Movie** object is much more limited than that of a regular AS3-based swf file.